# Insert multiple image links in database (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want users to be able to upload multiple images at a time.

Then the image will be resized and stored in the file system and a link to the image will be stored in the database (MySQL).

I could possibly retrieve the images like this:

```
Route::post('upload', function(){

    $files = Input::file('files');

    foreach($files as $file) {

        $file->move('uploads/');
    }
});
```

Then I'd get the links and store them in an array.

What would be the best way to store these links in the database?

Comment: Seems quite clear that the decent way is to create a `images` (or something similar) table and make it `One To Many` with `users` table, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a project that required uploading an image and resizing/cropping it to various sizes. The best way I found was to take the uploaded image and use [Image manipulation library package in laravel](https://github.com/Intervention/image) to resize it. You can easily manipulate images with this without having to deal with PHP graphic library directly. Then I hashed the current timestamp and the user id of the user together to get a unique name for the file system. After that I stored all the resized and original images in the file system with the unique name but appended small_, big_ and orig_ in front of the files. I stored only the unique name hash in the database. And each time I had to access the images I just appended whichever size I wanted and fetched it from the system.